# Is there any mechanism to achieve making authentication to non superuser other than using customized user model

Tags: django-models

I have been working with custom user model with classes of AbstactBaseUser and BaseUserManager to make authentication to users, but once i have done, it occurs to only authenticate and authorize a superuser and ignore to authenticate a normal user although they are authenticated with the similar specified credentials in the customized classes in models.py

I tried to delete all the stuff in the initial migration files and deleting all the users and making migrations again but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.